# How to provide "hint" for Live Photo

Tags: swift, phlivephoto

In the iOS Human Interface Guidelines under the Live Photos section Apple says this,

> "Make sure that users can distinguish a Live Photo from a traditional
>   still photo. It’s especially important to help users make this
>   distinction when they can share the photo. The best way to show users
>   that they’re viewing a Live Photo is to display a little movement that
>   gives a hint of the experience. In cases where a hint isn’t possible,
>   you can display the system-provided badge on the Live Photo. A Live
>   Photo never displays a playback button that looks like a video
>   playback button."

I am kind of confused on how to provide that little hint of movement in my live photo. **How do I provide that hint of movement?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to dissect a Live Photo into still frames and construct an animated UIImage, or dig out the Live Photo's movie file... It's much simpler.

1. Display your user's Live Photo content in a [`PHLivePhotoView`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHLivePhotoView_Class/index.html).
2. Call [`startPlaybackWithStyle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHLivePhotoView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/PHLivePhotoView/startPlaybackWithStyle:) and pass
   [`.Hint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PhotosUI/Reference/PHLivePhotoView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/PHLivePhotoViewPlaybackStyle) for the playback style to get the "hint" that the HIG is talking about.
3. There's no step three.

Comment: I actually tried this, but there was one issue. If I manually play it like that then the user can't play the live photo after the hint is executed.

Comment: They should be able to... That might be a bug, certainly [worth filing](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Comment: Ok, I'm going to play around with it once I get home. If it doesn't work I'm going to file a bug report.

Comment: Well for now since it's not working I am going to file a bug report. As this code should be working I am going to mark it as accepted so others can find this answer more easily.